# French character being converted to © sign

Tags: c#, encoding, smtp, html-email

I'm trying to send mail through SMTP in c#.

Sample Mail Content [in French] :

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /><body>
Votre compte à été activé
</body></html>
```

Mail Received : Votre compte Ã  Ã©tÃ© activÃ©

Could anyone help me why the mail content showing copyright sign in place of french chars.

Comment: You need to set `BodyEncoding` to `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: And ensure the originaltext is actually UTF8. If the original text comes from a file saved in an ASCII encoding (eg. aspx file, cs file), the result will still be wrong.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm assuming that the original content is a string.  Also, his problem text looks like UTF8-as-ASCII

Comment: the original content is stored in a string variable.I am directly passing this to MailMessage body.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are passing same string as you printed here "Votre compte à été activé" and using UTF-8 is good it can show any type of characters but you need to make sure it is same from where you are picking else you have to first save it correct.

If you are picking it from sql database you must use nvarchar data type to store any kind of characters. If it is varchar it will raise same issue.